# How can I find all common letters in a set of strings?

Tags: python

I've written code to find all common letters of 3 given strings. 
Unfortunately, there are some errors, which I can't find.
If someone of you could tell me how such a code could look like, I'd appreciate that.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: common letters? as in the letter "a" is in strings x, y, and z?

Comment: If you are just looking for a code review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would probably be more appropriate

Comment: Can you explain what the 3d grid is supposed to represent? I am having a hard time understanding the underlying idea of your algorithm.

Comment: A 3d grid will make your algorithm take O(N^3) time rather than O(N) time. Also a complicated approach will also make your algorithm harder to understand and debug, which is why I suggested a cleaner answer below. Apologies, since you said in your question that you don't want to read alternatives. If you can suggest why you need a 3-rank tensor (are you working with only 3 strings?) then we might be able to help more.

Comment: @dm03514: codereview is only for code which works, see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq I do not believe "please make my code work" is on-topic for *any* stackexchange site; though if the question was cast more like "this is the specific issue I am having with my code", or if the copy-pasted code was much smaller and the problem more well-defined, that would be more on-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: If this isn't homework, it's making something simple arbitrarily difficult. If it's an algorithm design problem, then it probably belongs on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Thanks everybody. The fact is that the code is consciously O(n³) - it's an exercise starting from O(n³) going to O(n). And the code here is - as mentioned - the one for O(n³).

Answer (score 8):

```
def commonLetters(*strings):
    return set.intersection(*map(set,strings))
```

Demo:

```
>>> commonLetters('abcdef', 'defg', 'def', 'ef')
{'e', 'f'}
```

Comment: `common_letters` ([PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names))

Comment: or `return set(strings[0]).intersection(*strings[1:])`

Answer (score 2):

Python is designed to make things simple to read, and to provide standard libraries for most functions--that's why it's "batteries included." The Pythonic way to do what you want to do is with set intersections.

```
>>> a = 'foobar'
>>> b = 'bar'
>>> c = 'barbaz'
>>> common_letters = set(a) & set(b) & set(c)
>>> print( list(common_letters) )
['a', 'r', 'b']
```

There are certainly other ways to construct the set, but the KISS principle definitely applies here.

Comment: You don't need to convert strings a, b, and c into lists -- they're already iterable sequences. Otherwise a good answer, IMHO.

Comment: @martineau You're right; I removed the extraneous list() calls for better clarity.